# Attempting to copy scoreboard to another scoreboard in 1.12.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Firstly, I have to use Minecraft v1.12.2 for plugin reasons. I need to use a command to copy a scoreboard, but I cant figure what I'm doing wrong.
I'm using the command: `/execute @a as run scoreboard players operation @s SavePoint1 = @s Scoreboard`

Comment: I'm not sure what the syntax for 1.12.2 is, does `/execute @a ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players operation @s SavePoint1 = @s Scoreboard` work? (I can't test it right now)

Answer (score 1):

Even for information about old Minecraft versions, the Minecraft wiki is very helpful, because there is a [list of revisions](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Scoreboard&action=history&limit=500) for every article. The first 1.13 snapshot came out in October 2017, so the most relevant revision for you would be the [last one before that](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Scoreboard&oldid=1156283).

This tells you that the correct command is:

```
/scoreboard players operation <selector> <scoreboard> = <selector> <scoreboard>
```

This is actually still the exact same syntax as today.

For the `/execute` part the same applies, [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Commands/execute&oldid=1130584) is the old version of the "Commands/execute" article. That tells you that the syntax back then was `execute @a ~ ~ ~`  instead of `execute as @a run`  today.

Comment: How would this work with a selector for multiple entities? So what happens when you use @a?

Comment: It goes through them all one by one. So if you for example use `>=`, it will choose the biggest one out of the list. With `=` it's the last one, so usually arbitrary, but you can use `sort=…`.

Comment: The person asking the question tried to do this: `/execute @a as run scoreboard players operation @s SavePoint1 = @s Scoreboard`. I'd assume they try to set the score for every player to a different score from the same player. I'm still unsure about how to do it without `/execute`. You'd obviously need to use @a as the first selector, but I can't think of anything for the second selector that would set the first score to the score of each individual player. `sort` would sort based on the position of the command block, not every player. `@p` would select the player closest to the command block.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Yes, then `execute` is indeed needed. But of course "as" before "@a".

Comment: This is for 1.12.2, so `as` wasn't a thing yet (Or at least I'm pretty sure it wasn't)

Comment: Got it. I changed my answer now.